# Can we Fixed High charts graph portion height irrespective of number of series or legends?

Tags: highcharts

I have different high charts as shown below. I have more number of series in one graph and have only one series  in other one, In this case in my actual screen graph portion of first graph is bigger than second one, so is it possible to keep graph height constant without considering number of series (legends which occupied height at bottom)?

[image: Graph1-big height of graph portion]

[image: Graph2-small height of graph portion]

Comment: There is not a particular setting for this. One option: figure out how much space you'll need for your largest legend, and set the `marginBottom` for all charts accordingly. Another: put the legend on the right instead of the bottom. Beyond that, you're probably looking at writing a callback function to adjust the sizes of the plot areas after they load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comment, you grab maximum of charts' margin bottom and set it for the rest of the chart. It should be set on load event in the last chart.

```
function adjustLegend() {
  var charts = Highcharts.charts;

  var marginBottomMax = charts
    .reduce((prevChart, currChart) => Math.max(prevChart.marginBottom, currChart.marginBottom));

  charts.forEach(chart => {
    if (chart.marginBottom < marginBottomMax) {
      chart.update({
        chart: {
          marginBottom: marginBottomMax
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

chart: {
  events: {
    load: adjustLegend
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/wsrtaq09/1/

If you know what should be the legend height, you can set [legend.maxHeight](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.maxHeight).

```
legend: {
  layout: 'vertical',
  maxHeight: 50,
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/wsrtaq09/2/